# Cypher query shortest path

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I build a graphe this way: the nodes represents: busStops, and the relationship represent the bus line linking bus stops each others.

The relationship type correspond to the time needed to go from a node two another one.

When I'm querying the graph (thanks to cypher) to get the shortestPath between two which are maybe not linked, the result is the one where the number of relations used is the smallest.

I would to change that in order that the shortest path corresponds to the path where the addition of all relationship types used between two nodes(which correspond to the time) is the smallest?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

first, you are doing it wrong. don't use a unique relationship type for each time. use one relationship type and then put a property "time" on all relations.

second, to calculate the addition you can use this cypher formula:

```
START from=node({busStopId1}), to=node({busStopId2})
MATCH p=from-[:LINE*]-to  //asterix * means any distance
RETURN p,reduce(total = 0, r in relationships(p): total + r.time) as tt
ORDER by tt asc;
```

Comment: No, the relationship type is an int like 2 or 3 the value in minutes.

Comment: you must change that. simply have only 1 relationship type, and put those minutes into relationship property.

Comment: relationship type is always just a name, it cannot be int and you cannot do calculations on its value

Comment: there's currently no way to cast from string to int in cypher, so it would be hard to calculate with a type as a number... AFAIK (as ulkas says). It's not outside the realm of possibility to be added, though...

Comment: Ok now the type is corresponding to the type of transportation (bike, foot, bus or metro). If I want a query that returns the same things but without taking care of the type I replace [:Line*] by [*] right?

Comment: it would be cool to be able to specifiy the cost-property with shortestPath or allShortestPaths
`shortestPath(n-[r:LINE*]-m,r.time)` if you want to see that, please raise a github issue.

Comment: Hi, I am building up the similar application. Issue is this query work if I have limited data set . In my application I have more than 85000 nodes and more than 5 lakh relationships/ connections in between them. The query executes for 15 minutes but doesnot respond with result set.

Comment: hi @IshaanPuniani, i need more info, maybe you could raise a new question with your example data set and query and link it here?

Comment: Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35753192/neo4j-query-for-shortest-path-stuck-do-not-work-if-i-have-2way-relationship-in/35816104?noredirect=1#comment59335830_35816104